# Italic font are missing from my Ubuntu install

Tags: 15.10, fonts

I have installed a fresh Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and I have a problem with italic font. Here's a screen shot :

[image]

The text inside italic tag on Wikipedia is not rendered. How can I install the missing italic fonts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First check that the meta-package for your desktop environment is installed correctly, since it depends on the base font packages. In your case that is:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
   ```
2. If the first step didn't pull in any new packages or the problem persists anyway, the base font packages seem to be broken and you need to re-install them:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall fonts-cantarell fonts-dejavu-core fonts-freefont-ttf
   ```
3. In the future, to detect packages with broken or missing files early you can use the [`debsums`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/debsums/) program and package, which comes with a Cron script to check package integrity on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the missing font from Internet,

Then place the font in font folder of ubuntu system/sys folder.

Reboot, It should start again..

PS I think you need to be admin for doing this.

Type in terminal

```
Sudo nautilus
```

for getting all the permission to access your home folder.

Comment: Do you have a link where I get the missing fonts?