# Italicized text disappears in Firefox & Thunderbird

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

after a fresh reinstall of Ubuntu 15.10 Gnome, I can no longer see italics in either Firefox or Thunderbird. More precisely:

- in Firefox, where text is typically pre-existing, parts of sentences are missing. Comparing with the content in Chrome, which displays correctly, I see that the missing parts are the italicized ones.
- in Thunderbird, this is even easier to see: I can type some text, select it, turn it to italics, and it disappears.

In both cases, it doesn't seem to be caused by italics changing color as the phenomenon is the same whatever I set background color to. Also, when text disappears, it is no longer selectable.

I tried disabling add-ons (in Firefox at least), no effect.

Thanks for any help!
F

Comment: 1. Check the page source (Ctrl+U) to confirm that the missing text is displayed. 2. Go to Preferences - Content - Fonts & Colors - Advanced and confirm fonts listed are valid (include italic characters). Also uncheck "Allow pages to choose fonts..." Then check to see if the problem persists.

Comment: 1. I checked the page source, text in italics was there.
2. I checked that listed fonts included italics (using gnome-specimen), it turned out that italics were missing for the default sans-serif font.
3. looked up askubuntu.com, followed the instructions in this thread:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/732390/italic-font-are-missing-from-my-ubuntu-install

and now I do have italics in Firefox and Thunderbird.
Thank you, user3169!

Answer (score 0):

For another data point:

I have had what seems to be a similar "disappearing text" issue in Thunderbird for the past week or two. I've never seen it before that time. To replicate:

1. Start Thunderbird 45.2.0 and create new message.
2. Select some text.
3. Click the "italic" icon OR hit Ctrl-I
4. The selected text disappears (as does the space between the preceding and following words -- in other words, there is no large blank space; the text and space it previously took up both disappear).
5. Note: Hit Ctrl-Z (Undo) and the text reappears.

Workaround: Use slashes or asterisks around the word to give emphasis.

My Thunderbird plugins are:

- Exchange EWS Provider
- Lightning

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 on a 2013-vintage 13" MacBook Air. It *does* have a couple of custom key bindings (to enable the ~ key, a known oddity of Linux on MacBook) but is otherwise pretty stock.

I have not been able to replicate this problem in Firefox.

Comment: Aaaannndd ... the problem went away (after about a month of constant annoyance) entirely without me doing anything here. Could this have been a Thunderbird bug that was fixed in an update? In any case, it would appear to be a font issue as noted above.